# Set input field placeholder from Date()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to dynamically set `<input type='date' placeholder='{{ 'currentDate' }}'>` placeholders, and my variable currentDate is `currentDate = this.datePipe.transform(new Date(), "yyyy-MM-dd");` , but this method does not work.

How does one use this to dynamically set placeholder currently dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use bindings for inserted dynamic values instead of string interpolation. Also use the datepipe in the recommendef way.

```
<input type="date" [placeholder]="currentDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" ...>


// in the *.ts

public currentDate: Date = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{{ 'currentDate' }}` => `{{ currentDate }}`